# Error when using os.system in python but not in shell

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to redirect the out of gnu make.
Want to redirect ALL to both STDOUT and all.log and error only to error.log.

Below is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import optparse
import os
import sys
import commands

command = 'make all > >(tee -a  all.log ) 2>&1 2> >(tee -a  error.log )'
SysReturnVal=os.system(command)

print "system return value is ", SysReturnVal
```

When I execute it getting

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
sh: -c: line 0: `make all > >(tee -a all.log  ) 2>&1 2> >(tee -a  error.log )'
```

But executing the same command on linux bash shell executes without error.

```
make all > >(tee -a  all.log ) 2>&1 2> >(tee -a  error.log )
```

Why is this failing when running in python script using os.system, but not in terminal/bash shell ?

Comment: Which shell are you using? It looks like you're trying to do some none-portable things that work in your shell but not with `sh`.

Comment: sh points to bash in centos 6.4. I tried the same command on bash and it works fine and in python the same command with os.system fails with sh errors.

Comment: When you run Bash via a symlink called `sh`, Bash will run in `sh` compatibility mode, and won't let you use any Bashisms. You can try running `/bin/sh` interactively and see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

`os.system` start `/bin/sh` and you have bashism in your command:

```
>(....)
```

You will need to start bash:

```
os.system("bash -c '{}'".format(command))
```

Also remember if you use single quotes in your command they need to be escaped to print: `'\''`, eg:

```
command="ls '\\''.'\\''"
# And it's even worse in single quotes:
command='ls \'\\\'\'.\'\\\'\''
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.system()` calls *nix `system()` call.

> The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process
>          that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3)
>          as follows:
>              execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);

More info : [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)

You have to do something like `os.system("/bin/bash <command>")`